# Do I have to set XMLResolver to null for preventing XXE attacks?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, .net-framework-version, xxe

I am trying to reproduce XXE scenario which is posted in the following link

https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md

As I read from the documentation, the following code block should not load the DTD when it is run with 4.5.2+ target framework version when XMLResolver is not set explicitly. However I see the content of the file. If I set XMLResolver to null it doesnt load the content as expected.

Why the target framework does not affect the result? My aim is to verify this scenario in here and apply the solution in my project.

```
static void LoadXML()
 {
   string xxePayload = "<!DOCTYPE doc [<!ENTITY win SYSTEM 'file:///C:/Users/testdata2.txt'>]>" 
                     + "<doc>&win;</doc>";
   string xml = "<?xml version='1.0' ?>" + xxePayload;

   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   // Setting this to NULL disables DTDs - Its NOT null by default.
   // xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;   
   xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
   Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.InnerText);
   Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the setting as been default to null as .NET 4.6 and not before  (even what you can read on OWASP CheatSheet). I recommand to put the xmlDoc.XmlResolver to null by default on all XML parsing to my dev even on .NET 4.6 framework

Answer (score 0):

Is your targetFramework in compilation or httpRuntime ?
Please check targetFramework in both.

```
<system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
      <!--... many other things -->
</system.web>
```